# How do I build an OS X installer package with a custom background with productbuild?

Tags: macos, installation, packagemaker, productbuild

I've got a project that relies on the now deprecated PackageMaker tool to create an installer for OS X. I'm working on updating it to use [pkgbuild](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/pkgbuild.1.html) and [productbuild](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productbuild.1.html). I'm trying to add a custom background to the installer by passing the `--resources` flag to `productbuild` with the directory containing the background image. I don't get any errors from the `productbuild` command, but when I open the package in Pacifist, I don't see my resources included at all. I've tried referencing the background image in `distribution.xml`, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I'm at a loss for what to try next to debug this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what my resource folder looks like:

[image]

As cmd parameter I use: `--resources /path/Resources`

Since I'm not using the PackageMaker GUI and my installer tool creates the Distribution XML file manually from various bits and pieces, I can only say that you have to specify this background.jpg file so that it ends up in the Distribution XML file as:

```
<background file="background.jpg" alignment="topleft" scaling="none"/>
```

Ie despite it being in the en.lproj folder the file should not be specified with a path.

Comment: Aha! I had copied the background element in the file from my old packagemaker distribution that was `resources/background.png`. Changing it to just `background.png` did the trick. I guess the starting path changed in the new tool. Thanks!