# How does one set a background image in an OSX .pkg?

Tags: macos, installation, package, pkgbuild

I am creating a .pkg installer for my OSX application and I am having trouble figuring out how to set the background image.

I am creating my installer in my build script like this:

```
pkgbuild --root $APP_FOLDER --identifier "com.company.product" $FINAL_PKG
```

This works great but I have not been able to find any information about setting the background image in the man pages. I have seen package installers that have custom background images, how does one set it?

EDIT:

Here is a screenshot of a package installer with a custom background:

[image]

Comment: are you talking about your icns?

Comment: No as you are installing, some package installers have a custom background image instead of the normal pencil, ruler and paintbrush background that is the default. I have added a screenshot to my post.

Comment: Oh yeah.... did you look at the command line parameters from productbuild ? Go to terminal and type in just 'productbuild"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah ha! There is a resources flag that goes along with productbuild. Here is a stackoverflow question addressing the resources: [How do I build an OS X installer package with a custom background with productbuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963465/how-do-i-build-an-os-x-installer-package-with-a-custom-background-with-productbu)

It mentions --resources /path/Resources

and an en.lproj subdirectory, and an XML resources file.  You can specify the background.jpg or modify an existing one.

Hope this points you in the right direction(s).

Answer (score 2):

This was most likely done with a tool apple had for creating installers.

You might be able to find it if you search for it on the OS X developer site of Apple

**EDIT:**

See also

- [installease](http://www.absolute.com/en/products/installease)
- [Vise](http://www.mindvision.com)
- [InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/index.html)

**NOTE:**

I don't think an installer is the best solution! Making your app in a way that frees you from an installer is not hard. License Agreement, Pre- and Post script functions can be coded in-app.

Comment: The only thing I have seen like this from Apple is PackageMaker but that seems to have been abandoned.