# How to set background image in MacOS Mojave pkg installer using productbuild?

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, productbuild

I'm using `productbuild` to create a .pkg installer for MacOS Mojave. I've read the [schema reference for the Distribution.xml file](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/DistributionDefinitionRef/Chapters/Distribution_XML_Ref.html). I am successfully using this to include a custom welcome. Therefore I know my resource path is being used correctly when I run:

`productbuild --resources ./res --sign "$PKG_SIGN_ID" --distribution Distribution.xml foo.pkg`

But I can't seem to create a custom background image. I've tried various jpg and png images.

I have read [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576534/how-does-one-set-a-background-image-in-an-osx-pkg) and I've tried with and without a `en.lproj` subdirectory within my resources directory.

My `Distribution.xml` ends up looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<installer-gui-script minSpecVersion="1">
<background file="background.jpg" mime-type="image/jpeg" scaling="tofit"/>
<welcome file="welcome.html"/>
<title>My App</title>
    <pkg-ref id="com.foo.myapp"/>
    <options customize="never" require-scripts="false"/>
    <choices-outline>
        <line choice="default">
            <line choice="com.foo.myapp"/>
        </line>
    </choices-outline>
    <choice id="default"/>
    <choice id="com.foo.myapp" visible="false">
        <pkg-ref id="com.foo.myapp"/>
    </choice>
    <pkg-ref id="com.foo.myapp" version="1.0" onConclusion="none">foo.pkg</pkg-ref>
</installer-gui-script>
```

Is this no longer possible to do with Mojave?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the issue. My problem was I was running in "Dark Mode".

If you want to set the background image of an installer for DarkMode you need to use the tag `background-darkAqua` otherwise it will never show:

```
<background-darkAqua file="background.png" mime-type="image/png" scaling="tofit"/>
```

Comment: i used this but my installer section like introduction,summary etc are all black which are not clear due to this image.

Comment: No problems with that for me. Send me your Distribution.xml or share a link